# In python, how do I take the highest occurrence of something in a list, and sort it that way?

Tags: python, list, list-manipulation

```
[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2]
```

Would be:

```
[ (3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 1) ]
```

The output should be sorted by highest count first to lowest count. In this case, 3 to 2 to 1.

Comment: Do the groups all occur together or could you have `[3,4,2,3,4,3]` and expect the same output? Does the order of the output list matter in any way?

Comment: In your example, the output would still be the same.

Comment: Appears to be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829470/ranking-elements-of-multiple-lists-by-their-count-in-python).  The accepted answer there directly gives you working code for this, in any case: `freq_sorted([3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], include_freq=True)` gives the *exact* result you ask for.

Comment: At **855 Questions**, I'm beginning to wonder if you ever try anything yourself first or are you trying to crowd-source a software project...

Comment: @John actually I like this kind of questions, I hope to see thousands more from TIMEX.

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate.  It's also homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2]
result = []
for entry in set(data):
    result.append((entry, data.count(entry)))
result.sort(key = lambda x: -x[1])
print result

>>[(3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: The output should be sorted by highest count first to lowest count.

Comment: so `print sorted(result, key=lambda x: -x[1])` instead of `print result`

Comment: and `result = sorted(result, key = lambda x: -x[1])` can be written as `result.sort(key = lambda x: -x[1])`

Comment: See O(n**2) comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829470/ranking-elements-of-multiple-lists-by-their-count-in-python/1829558#1829558

Comment: @TIMEX: Yes, it's a loop bounded by O(n) (data.count) inside a loop bounded by O(n) (the outer for loop).  In other words, each item has to do something to every other item, or n*n, which is n**2.

Comment: The solution can be made more succinct. Rather than initiating `result` as an empty list and using a for loop with `append`, one can use list comprehension: `result = [(entry, data.count(entry)) for entry in set(data)]` (cf. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html, section 5.1.4).

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections#collections.Counter) in Python 2.7+ ([this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/) works on 2.5+):

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter([3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2]).most_common()
# [(3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: TIMEX, haven't you heard that Python comes with 'batteries included'?

Comment: But Counter is a new collection class.:) This is correct answer if on 2.7 or 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Try using a collections.Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
data = [3,4,2,3,4,3]
Counter(data).most_common()
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? I think Counter was introduced in 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you choose an O(n**2) algorithm to do this. The alternative to Counter (if you have <2.7) is not too difficult

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> L=[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2]
>>> D=defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in L:
...     D[i]+=1
... 
>>> sorted(D.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[(3, 3), (4, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfun(x,y):
    return x[1]-y[1]

list1 = [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2]
s1 = set(list1)
newlist = []
for e in s1:
    newlist.append((e,list1.count(e)))
print sorted(newlist,cmp=myfun)
```

I think, this is what you asked for. Sorry for hurry with the first answer. But just note that `cmp` argument for sorted is not available in python3

Comment: See O(n**2) comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829470/ranking-elements-of-multiple-lists-by-their-count-in-python/1829558#1829558.