# Take a list, sort by popularity and then remove duplicates

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In python, how do I take the highest occurrence of something in a list, and sort it that way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791599/in-python-how-do-i-take-the-highest-occurrence-of-something-in-a-list-and-sort)

Hi all,

I am looking for an easy way to sort a list by popularity and then remove duplicate elements.

For example, given a list:

```
[8, 8, 1, 1, 5, 8, 9]
```

I would then end up with a list like the following:

```
[8, 1, 5, 9]
```

Comment: You should give a better example. In yours, the order of popularity is the same as the natural order of the digits. If you had two nines, would it be `[1,3,9,5]` ?

Comment: Yes. sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @kahm: You can't sort a list by popularity.  You have to create some other intermediate structure that contains the counts.  What other structures have you looked at?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@SilentGhost has an excellent solution for Python 2.7+. A relatively simple solution for 2.6 and older:

```
a = [8, 8, 1, 1, 5, 8, 9]

popularity = sorted(set(a), key=lambda x: -a.count(x))

[8, 1, 5, 9]
```

This solution is, however, expensive (because of `count`).

Here another, better solution with temporary dictionary:

```
a = [8, 8, 1, 1, 5, 8, 9]
d = {}
for i in a:
    d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
popularity = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
```

Comment: this is very expensive for large lists.

Comment: @SilentGhost - you're right. I have added a better solution with dict.

Comment: i'd think `key=d.get` would suffice.

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> lst = [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 9]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(lst)
>>> [i for i, j in c.most_common()]
[1, 3, 5, 9]
```

see [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) docs for the links to legacy versions-compatible implementations.

Comment: You should mention that `Counter` is only available in Python 2.7+. Here is an implementation for pre 2.7: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/ (or one can just use a normal loop and dict ;))

Comment: @Felix: before `Counter`, there is `defaultdict` :)